# Custom pgfplots spy: Dimension too large

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, spy

I'm working on presenting some Nyquist-diagrams with the help of the `bodeplot` package, but the same situation applies, when using default `pgfplots`.

The problem is that I need to point out details of the plot, so I try to implement what is called a *spy* or which could be described as a *magnifying glass* for a portion of the graph. However, I can not use

```
    \usetikzlibrary{spy}
```

as `spy` magnifies everything, including line thickness, in the region in question. This in turn does not improve the situation, as (for my special use case) the graph needs to show, whether the blue line passes the red cross left or right. To overcome this, I reworked the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116637/rectangular-spy-in-pgfplots-without-scaling) to suit my needs.

The result is depicted in the following screenshot:
[image]
My solution works by putting the entire `axis`-environment together with corresponding plots inside a `\newcommandx*` (the `newcommand`-equivalent of the `xargs` package, to have multiple optional arguments), and call it once to print the left plot. Then I use coordinates from this plot to calculate the center for the second plot, create a `scope` environment, call the macro for theplot inside the scope, and finally create a bounding box and clip the unnecessary parts.

The MWE for the picture above is:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{bodeplot}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{xargs}

    \usetikzlibrary{math, calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{fpu}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

    % A path that follows the edges of the current page
    \tikzstyle{reverseclip}=[insert path={(current page.north east) --
            (current page.south east) --
            (current page.south west) --
            (current page.north west) --
            (current page.north east)}
    ]

    \begin{document}


    \tikzmath{
        \c{1}= 333.3333;
        \a{22}= -3.0049;
        \a{23}= 3.0049;
        \a{33}= -7.1429;
        \b{3}= 0.9736;
    }

    \tikzmath{%
        \spyfactor = 4.0;%
        \sI = 1.0/\spyfactor;%
        \spyviewersize = 0.5\textwidth-5mm;%
    }%

    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
            outer sep=0pt,%
            % show background rectangle,%
            background rectangle/.style={%
                    draw=red,%
                },%
            spy-magnified/.style={%
                    draw,
                    /pgfplots/every axis,
                    rectangle,
                    inner sep=0pt,%
                    minimum height=\spyviewersize,
                    minimum width=\spyviewersize,
                },%
            spy-original/.style={%
                    draw,
                    /pgfplots/every axis,
                    rectangle,
                    inner sep=0pt,%
                    minimum height=\sI*\spyviewersize,
                    minimum width=\sI*\spyviewersize,
                },%
            remember picture,
        ]%



        \newcommandx*{\theaxis}[2][1={}, 2={}]{%
            \begin{axis}[
                bode@style,
                domain=5:100,
                scale only axis,
                width=\spyviewersize,
                height=\spyviewersize,
                axis equal,%
                xticklabel style={overlay},
                yticklabel style={overlay},
                % xlabel style={overlay},
                ylabel style={overlay},
                xlabel={$\operatorname{Re}(G_o(j\omega))$},%
                    ylabel={$\operatorname{Im}(G_o(j\omega))$},%
                % at={(0,0)},
                #1
                ]%

                % critical point
                \addplot [only marks,mark=+,thick,red] (-1 , 0);
                \coordinate (coordA) at (axis cs:-1,0);

                % Frequenzgang
                \addNyquistZPKPlot[%
                blue,%
                very thick,%
                samples=100,%
                #2
                ]%
                {%
                z/{-0.5, -2},%
                p/{0, 0, -40, \a{22},\a{33}},%
                k/{780130}%
                }%;%
            \end{axis}
        }%
        \theaxis[]

        % location for lower left corner of axis
        \coordinate (coordC) at (current axis.south west);

        %  location for spynode
        \coordinate[right=0.25\linewidth+0.75cm of current axis.east](coordB) ;

        % % draw the spy node and magnified spy node
        \node[spy-magnified] (spynode) at (coordB){};
        \node[spy-original] (spypoint) at (coordA){};

        \tikzmath{
            \spyscale = \spyfactor/(\spyfactor-1);
        }


        % % draw the connection lines
        \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
            \begin{scope}
                % \clip ($(spynode.south west) - (0.2pt, 0.2pt)$) rectangle ($(spynode.north east) + (0.2pt, 0.2pt)$) [reverseclip];
                \path [clip] (spynode.south west) -- (spynode.south east) -- (spynode.north east) -- (spynode.north west) -- cycle [reverseclip];
                \draw[dashed, /pgfplots/every axis] (spypoint.north west) -- (spynode.north west);
                \draw[dashed, /pgfplots/every axis] (spypoint.south east) -- (spynode.south east);
                \draw[dashed, /pgfplots/every axis] (spypoint.north east) -- (spynode.north east);
                \draw[dashed, /pgfplots/every axis] (spypoint.south west) -- (spynode.south west);
            \end{scope}
        \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

        \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
            \begin{scope}

                % comment the following line in for the final result, uncomment it for debugging to see placement of magnified axis
                \clip ($(spynode.south west) + (0.2pt, 0.2pt)$) rectangle ($(spynode.north east) - (0.2pt, 0.2pt)$);
                \theaxis[
                    scale around={\spyfactor:($(spynode)!\spyscale!(spypoint)$)},
                    mark options={
                            scale=\sI,
                        },
                    % additional styles for magnified axis go here
                ][
                    % additional styles for magnified nyquist plot go here
                    green,
                ]

            \end{scope}
        \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

        \node[anchor=north] (CP) at (coordB) {\scriptsize$(-1, 0)$};

    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{document}
```

(If you were to replicate this using standard pgfplots, then replace `\addNyquistZPKPlot` by an `\addplot` command, and remove the style `bode@style` from the axis environment.)

Notice, that I am reprinting the entire plot, only clipping it down afterwards. To see this, you can comment out the `\clip` command, which compiles to the following image:
[image]

This is obviously working well so far, however:

## Problem

When I use a bigger magnifying factor (say, set `\spyfactor=16.0;`), then `lualatex` gives an error `Dimension too lartge.` This is the corresponding log entry:

```
    \openout3 = gnuplot/mwe2.gnuplot
    PGFPlots: reading {gnuplot/mwe2.table}
    d:/desktop/tmp 01/mwe.tex:146: Dimension too large.
    <recently read> \pgf@x 
          
    l.146             ]
                    
    I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
    Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.
```

This is of course not too surprising, as the pgfplots engine has to produce a way too big image (of which I hardly show anything).

Hence my question is: What should I do to remedy this situation?

Possible solutions I have thought of, but am not capable of implementing, are:

1. Limit the drawing region for the second axis call. However, then I need to find a new way to scale and shift, because the red cross is not necessarily in the same position.
2. Use the fpu engine in some way, until all the cropping is done?
3. Go back to original spy library and find a way to rescale the line thickness.

I'm hoping for your advice, insights and possibly a solution. Thanks.

<strike>Addendum 1:</strike>
<strike>If someone with more reputation than 300 could create a tag for the `bodeplot` package, that would be great.</strike> Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{bodeplot}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\tikzmath{
\c{1}=333.3333;
\a{22}=-3.0049;
\a{23}=3.0049;
\a{33}=-7.1429;
\b{3}=0.9736;
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\zoomw}{50}
\begin{axis}[
bode@style,
scale only axis,
axis equal,
width=5cm, height=5cm,
xlabel={$\operatorname{Re}(G_o(j\omega))$},
ylabel={$\operatorname{Im}(G_o(j\omega))$},
clip=false,
]
\addNyquistZPKPlot[
blue, very thick,
domain=5:100,
samples=100,
] { z/{-0.5,-2}, p/{0,0,-40,\a{22},\a{33}}, k/{780130}};
\addplot[mark=+, thick, red] (-1,0);
\coordinate (sw1) at (-\zoomw,-\zoomw);
\coordinate (nw1) at (-\zoomw,\zoomw);
\coordinate (ne1) at (\zoomw,\zoomw);
\coordinate (se1) at (\zoomw,-\zoomw);
\draw (sw1) rectangle (ne1);
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
at={(6cm,0cm)},
bode@style,
scale only axis,
width=5cm, height=5cm,
xmin=-\zoomw, xmax=\zoomw,
ymin=-\zoomw, ymax=\zoomw,
xtick distance=100, ytick distance=100,
xticklabels=\empty, yticklabels=\empty,
]
\addplot[mark=+, thick, red] (-1,0);
\addNyquistZPKPlot[
green, very thick,
domain=16:100,
samples=100,
] { z/{-0.5,-2}, p/{0,0,-40,\a{22},\a{33}}, k/{780130}};
\coordinate (sw2) at (-\zoomw,-\zoomw);
\coordinate (nw2) at (-\zoomw,\zoomw);
\coordinate (ne2) at (\zoomw,\zoomw);
\coordinate (se2) at (\zoomw,-\zoomw);
\end{axis}
\draw[dashed] (sw1) -- (sw2) (nw1) -- (nw2) (ne1) -- (ne2) (se1) -- (se2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`\newcommand{\zoomw}{50}`
[image: Graph with zoom]
`\newcommand{\zoomw}{5}`
[image: Graph with high zoom]

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a promising start. I have two concerns about that approach, though. The first one is the centering of the magnified red cross, which can easily be achieved by subtracting 1 from the xmin, xmax, and sw2, nw2, ne2 and se2 x coordinates. The second one seems not so easy: Since the tick lines on the original axis vary dependent on the actual plot, it is hard to manually set them for the second axis. Is there a way to save and copy the calculated tick options and insert them into the second axis?

Comment: Can you not use `xtick distance=100, ytick distance=100,` for both plots? I am sure there must be some way to extract this distance, but I can not think of it. -a new question?

Comment: In theory, I can. But I liked it better, if it was automated. I added my own answer based on yours, with an automated approach to scaling the second grid. However, I can also see the appeal of deliberately having a finer grid in the spy.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was almost content with the answer of @hpekristiansen, I changed up the small concerns I had. It turned out to be quite an adventure, but here is my appended code:

```
            \documentclass{article}
            \usepackage{pgfplots}
            \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
            \usepackage{bodeplot}
            \usepackage{amsmath}
            \usetikzlibrary{math}

    \begin{document}
    \tikzmath{
        \c{1}=333.3333;
        \a{22}=-3.0049;
        \a{23}=3.0049;
        \a{33}=-7.1429;
        \b{3}=0.9736;
    }

    \tikzmath{int \tick;}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \newcommand{\zoomw}{50}
        \begin{axis}[
            bode@style,
            scale only axis,
            axis equal,
            width=5cm, height=5cm,
            xlabel={$\operatorname{Re}(G_o(j\omega))$},
                ylabel={$\operatorname{Im}(G_o(j\omega))$},
            xticklabel style={%
                    name=xtick\ticknum,
                    append after command=\pgfextra{\xdef\lastxticknum{\ticknum}},%
                },
            yticklabel style={%
                    name=ytick\ticknum,
                    append after command=\pgfextra{\xdef\lastyticknum{\ticknum}},%
                },
            clip=false,
            after end axis/.code={
                    \tikzmath{
                        \tickx=int(\lastxticknum-1);
                        \ticky=int(\lastyticknum-1);
                    }
                    \coordinate (O) at (axis cs:0,0);
                    \coordinate (X) at (axis cs:1,1);
                    \path let \p1=($(xtick\lastxticknum.base)-(xtick\tickx.base)$),
                    \p2=($(ytick\lastyticknum.east)-(ytick\ticky.east)$),
                    \p3=($(X)-(O)$),
                    \n1={\x1/\x3},
                    \n2={\y2/\y3}
                    in
                    \pgfextra{%
                        \pgfmathparse{int(round(min(\n1, 2*\zoomw)))}
                        \xdef\tickdistx{\pgfmathresult}
                        \pgfmathparse{int(round(min(\n2, 2*\zoomw)))}
                        \xdef\tickdisty{\pgfmathresult}
                    };
                },
            ]
            \addNyquistZPKPlot[
            blue, very thick,
            domain=5:100,
            samples=100,
            ] { z/{-0.5,-2}, p/{0,0,-40,\a{22},\a{33}}, k/{780130}};
            \addplot[mark=+, thick, red] (-1,0);
            \coordinate (sw1) at (-\zoomw-1,-\zoomw);
            \coordinate (nw1) at (-\zoomw-1,\zoomw);
            \coordinate (ne1) at (\zoomw-1,\zoomw);
            \coordinate (se1) at (\zoomw-1,-\zoomw);
            \draw (sw1) rectangle (ne1);
        \end{axis}
        \begin{axis}[
                at={(6cm,0cm)},
                bode@style,
                scale only axis,
                width=5cm, height=5cm,
                xmin=-\zoomw-1, xmax=\zoomw-1,
                ymin=-\zoomw, ymax=\zoomw,
                xtick distance=\tickdistx,
                ytick distance=\tickdisty,
                xticklabels=\empty, yticklabels=\empty,
            ]
            \addplot[mark=+, thick, red] (-1,0);
            \addNyquistZPKPlot[
            green, very thick,
            domain=16:100,
            samples=100,
            ] { z/{-0.5,-2}, p/{0,0,-40,\a{22},\a{33}}, k/{780130}};
            \coordinate (sw2) at (-\zoomw-1,-\zoomw);
            \coordinate (nw2) at (-\zoomw-1,\zoomw);
            \coordinate (ne2) at (\zoomw-1,\zoomw);
            \coordinate (se2) at (\zoomw-1,-\zoomw);
        \end{axis}
        \draw[dashed] (sw1) -- (sw2) (nw1) -- (nw2) (ne1) -- (ne2) (se1) -- (se2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

`\newcommand{\zoomw}{50}`
[image: w:50]

`\newcommand{\zoomw}{110}`
[image: w:110]

My solution has the following features:

1. automatic adjustment of grid in the spy
2. red cross is aligned at the center of the spy

Of course I also can think of situations, where you'd want neither of them.