# Spy functionality with different scaling for each axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, spy

I would like to have a spy functionality that doesn't scale the linewidth and of which the scaling of each axis can be controlled separately.

The MWE is based on these questions: [Using tikzlibrary spy without magnifying line width and/or mark size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59036/using-tikzlibrary-spy-without-magnifying-line-width-and-or-mark-size) & [Rectangular spy in pgfplots without scaling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116637/rectangular-spy-in-pgfplots-without-scaling). The only thing missing is that I would like the spyviewer to be stretched vertically (being a square), while the spypoint should remain the same.

A possible solution would be something like `\begin{scope}[xscale around={...}]`, but that doesn't exist apparently.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,spy,calc}
\newcommand*\subfigheight{\linewidth}
\newcommand*\subfigwidth{\linewidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line=left,
    axis x line=bottom,
    style=thick,
    xmin=-5, xmax=5,
    ymin=-5, ymax=30,
    width=\subfigwidth,
    height=\subfigheight,
    ]
    \addplot[black,smooth,mark=none,domain=-5:5] {x^2};

    % Spy
    \newcommand*\spyfactor{2.}
    \newcommand*\spypoint{axis cs:0,0}
    \newcommand*\spyviewer{axis cs:0,20}
    \newcommand*\spypointwidth{0.1*\subfigwidth}
    \newcommand*\spypointheight{0.02*\subfigwidth}
    \node[thin, rectangle, draw, minimum width=\spypointwidth, minimum height=\spypointheight, inner sep=0pt] (spypoint) at (\spypoint) {};
    \node[rectangle, draw, fill=white, minimum width=\spyfactor^2*\spypointwidth, minimum height=\spyfactor^2*\spypointheight, inner sep=0pt] (spyviewer) at (\spyviewer) {};
    \draw[thin]  (spypoint) edge (spyviewer);
    \begin{scope}
      \clip ($(spyviewer.south west)+(\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)$) rectangle ($(spyviewer.north east)-(\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)$);
      \pgfmathparse{\spyfactor^2/(\spyfactor-1)}
      \begin{scope}[scale around={\spyfactor:($(\spyviewer)!\spyfactor^2/(\spyfactor^2-1)!(\spypoint)$)}]
        \addplot[black,smooth,mark=none,domain=-10:10] {x^2};
      \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

[image: MWE]